# javascript focus() not working from tab1 to tab2 in primefaces

Tags: javascript, validation, primefaces

I am using functionality where if validation error comes then goto link is generating an id of required component with focus() on the top of the page. On click of that link the required component is highlighted. Now its working if error is in same tab. But first tab is active focus function not pointing the required text box inside third tab.

```
void encodeGotoLabel(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, ResponseWriter writer,
            FacesMessage msg) throws IOException {
            String id = getid(context, msg);
            if (id != null && !FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO.equals(msg.getSeverity())
                && !FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL.equals(msg.getSeverity())) {
                String inputLabel = findInputLabel(context, id);

                if (inputLabel != null) {
                    ResourceBundle bundle ="bundle";

                    writer.writeText(" (", null);
                    writer.writeText(bundle.getString("goTo") + " ", null);
                    writer.startElement("a", component);
                    writer.writeAttribute("href", "javascript:document.getElementById('" + id
                        + "').focus();",
                        null);
                    writer.writeText(inputLabel, null);
                    writer.endElement("a");
                    writer.writeText(")", null);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: maybe element id is same, so you can only get the first element.

Comment: question not clear, what is it exactly that you need?

Comment: do you want to switch to tab where there is a validation error ??

Comment: Yes.. I am getting all error message on the first tab itself including all tabs required fields. But focus is only working  if required fields are need on same tab. Suppose i am on first tab i want focus to switch the tabs then point to respective required field.

Comment: have you work it out?

Comment: It will access all the required fields on the tabs. I want to access only those whose client id is generated on the top.

Comment: @BillyHope Hey It got resolved with widgetvar.select(index). I am adding attribute to all required fields and this way its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function loops on a group of tabs and check if there is an error, if so it switch to it and focus on the required field, all you need to do is add it in your function :

```
var tabs = PF('tabViewWv').getLength(); //tabViewWv is WidgetVar name
for (var iter = 1; iter <= tabs ; iter++) {
    if ($('#form\\:tabView\\:tab' + iter).find(':input').hasClass('ui-state-error')) {
        PF('tabViewWv').select(iter - 1);
        return false;
    }
}
```